# Drupal 7 - db_select: SQL function in where condition

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-7

I need to use this condition in my select statement:

```
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

but if I do, like this:

```
$query = db_select('table', 't');
$query->fields('t');
$query->condition('YEAR\(date\)', 'YEAR(CURDATE())', '=');
```

Drupal won't have it (even if I do not escape those parenthesis - it simply ignores them) because I get an error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'YEARdate' in 'where clause':
```

How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. just like this, it seems:

```
$query->where('YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())');
```

The `where` allows for the arbitrary SQL:

> The where() method allows for the addition of arbitrary SQL as a conditional fragment. $snippet may contain any legal SQL fragment, and if it has variable content it must be added using a named placeholder. The $args array is an array of placeholders and values that will be substituted into the snippet. It is up to the developer to ensure that the snippet is valid SQL. No database-specific modifications are made to the snippet.

Comment: Use addExpression , see my post

Answer (score 0):

Hm, you could also use [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x), it allow you to write SQL queries "without Drupal".
I mean, you'll be able to add custom WHERE statements or any SQL-proper functions, like custom functions ;)

Eg.

`$result = db_query('SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE type = "%s" AND title LIKE "%%%s%%"', 'type', 'title');`

Answer (score 0):

Use `addExpression` method : 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7.x

```
$query = db_select('table', 't');
$query->fields('t');
$query->addExpression('YEAR(t.date) = YEAR(CURDATE())');
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

var_dump($result);
```